# Haskell error: `Qualified name in binding position`

Tags: haskell

Here is the code:

```hs
import qualified View.TreeWidget as TreeWidget

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ bla "sdfsd"

bla someString = case someString of
  TreeWidget.name -> True
  "sdfsd" -> False
  _ -> True
```

`TreeWidget.name` is a function defined in a file `TreeWidget.hs` like this:

```hs
name :: String
name = "tree_list_name"
```

Here is the error:

```
src/View/Main.hs:8:3: error:
    Qualified name in binding position: TreeWidget.name
  |
8 |   TreeWidget.name -> True
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see a lower case pattern, that means a variable which matches everything. You might as well use a pattern wildcard (`_`) if the variable is not used on the right-hand side.

```hs
  name -> True
```

A pattern variable functions as a binder, you cannot substitute a pattern like `"tree_list_name" -> ..` with

```
  name -> ..

name :: String
name = "tree_list_name"
```

It also means you can't reference a pattern variable from some other module, which is what `TreeWidget.name` is doing.

The solution is to use [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html?highlight=patternsynonyms#extension-PatternSynonyms). In the `View.TreeWidget` module write something like

```hs
{-# Language PatternSynonyms #-}

module View.TreeWidget (pattern Name) where

pattern Name :: String
pattern Name = "tree_list_name"
```

Now you can use `Name` both as an expression and a pattern. So you can now write

```hs
import qualified View.TreeWidget as TreeWidget

bla :: String -> Bool
bla TreeWidget.Name = True
bla "sdfsd"         = False
bla _               = True
```

Answer (score 2):

As Iceland_jack explained, you can't use values like `name` as patterns. What you can use as patterns is essentially *constructors and literals*, where constructors are normally the uppercase things appearing in a `data` declaration like `Just` and `Nothing` in the `Maybe` type. The `PatternSynonyms` extension allows defining custom constructors for already declared types.

However, although I generally favour patterns over equality check, this seems to be a case where it would make more sense to just check whether `someString == TreeWidget.name` and act accordingly. This can easily be done with guards:

```
bla someString
 | someString==TreeWidget.name  = True
bla "sdfsd" = False
bla _ = True
```

Of course, since the result is again a boolean you could also just use logical operators:

```
bla someString = someString==TreeWidget.name || someString/="sdfsd"
```

If you have a taste for point-freeness, this can also be written

```
bla = or . ([(==TreeWidget.name), (/="sdfsd")]<*>) . pure
```

... but more effective would be to just use a shorter name for `someString`.

Comment: Best is to avoid `String` all together and define a datatype like `data Tag = TreeListName | ..` or something depending on the application

Comment: @Iceland_jack quite possibly, though it's hard to tell what the OP is really trying to do.